# What are some ancient words that mean forgiveness?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, ancient-greek, germanic

What are some ancient words that mean forgiveness? I’m looking for words that were used before the common era (before 0 CE). I’m looking for words from Latin, Greek, German, and other languages. These words can be nouns, verbs, or adjectives.

Answer (score 6):

Was this question overlooked because of Thanksgiving?

**Nouns**

- *venia*: typically used of the gods for indulgence or permission, but developed a meaning of "pardon" or "forgiveness" already with Cicero (if not earlier)
- *remissio*:  this became the Ecclesiastical word for forgiveness of sin
- *clementia*: this adds a connotation of "merciful" to the forgiveness
- *ignoscentia*: post-classical "very rare" but makes etymological sense

**Verbs**

- *ignoscere*: takes a dative; the most basic way to express forgiving someone/asking for forgiveness
- *condonare*: it means "to give up", but you can "give up" a grudge or debt, thus the forgiving aspect
- *concedere*: less common, but the basic idea is withdraw -> to allow -> to forgive someone (dat.) of crimes (acc.)

**Adjectives**

- *exorabilis*: "easily moved", i.e. forgiving if entreated
- *clemens*: adjective, from which the noun *clementia* is derived

Answer (score 4):

The standard Classical Greek words are συγγιγνώσκω "forgive" and συγγνώμη or σύγγνοια "forgiveness".

Comment: Also: ἐλεέω (cf. "kyrie eleison"--but the word is in classical sources too)

Comment: @brianpck Yes, though that's more "show pity/mercy to" than "forgive" (i.e. no implication that someone has wronged you). Semantically quite close of course.

Comment: @TKR Interesting, there semantic similarities is present in English, too. One theoretical to translate νηλής besides "pitiless" is "ruthless" or "**unforgiving**."

Answer (score 3):

In the gospels, the verb seems to be [ἀφίημι](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CF%86%CE%AF%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%B9), meaning literally to let go. See, for example, Mark 1:4.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot give you any German examples, as there are no German (or Germanic) texts from before the common era, but we do have Sanskrit mṛḑīka-, Avestan marždika- et al.